# A lattice that is "closed" w.r.t. a containing poset

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

According to [the Wikipedia article for 'Lattice'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Sublattices), a sublattice is a non-empty subset of a lattice $L$ that is a lattice with the same meet and join operations as $L$.

I'd like to know if there is a name for the following generalization of this concept. Let $\mathbf{P}=(P,\leq)$ be a poset (which is not necessarily a lattice), and let $L\subseteq P$ satisfy the following conditions.

1. For every $x,y \in L$ there is a greatest lower bound for $\{x,y\}$ in $\mathbf{P}$, and it belongs to $L$.
2. For every $x,y \in L$ there is a least upper bound for $\{x,y\}$ in $\mathbf{P}$, and it belongs to $L$.

Is there a standard name for the type of "sub-lattice" that $L$ is?

It is technically not a sublattice, because $\mathbf{P}$ is not known to be a lattice. However, it won't do simply to say that $(L,\leq)$ forms a lattice, because it is possible for a subset $L$ of $P$ to form a lattice under $\mathbf{P}$'s partial order without satisfying the above conditions. Take, for instance, the following counter-example.

Denote by $P$ the powerset of $\{0,1,2\}$, and denote by $\leq$ set containment. Set $L := \left\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1\}, P\right\}$. Then $(L,\leq)$ is a lattice, however it doesn't satisfy condition 2 above, because the least upper bound for $\left\{\{0\},\{1\}\right\}$ in $\mathbf{P} = (P,\leq)$ is $\{0,1\} \notin L$.

Answer (score 2):

The same type of question arises frequently in semigroup theory. Let $M$ be a monoid with identity $1$ and let $e \not= 1$ by an idempotent of $M$.
You may have a subsemigroup of $M$ which forms a monoid (or even a group) with identity $e$. For instance the subsemigroup $eMe$ is a monoid with identity $e$ and the [$\mathcal{H}$-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) of $e$ is a group.

In semigroup theory, various names have be proposed. The monoid $eMe$ is sometimes called the *local monoid* at $e$. A subsemigroup of a semigroup $S$ which turns out to be a group is sometimes called a group **in** $S$ (or inside $S$).

To come back to your question, you may call $L$ an *ordered subset forming a lattice* or perhaps *a lattice inside $\mathbf{P}$*. But don't forget to give a precise definition if you want to use this non standard terminology.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting, however, I'm not sure the analogy is quite correct, because as my counterexample shows, it is possible for a subset $L$ of $P$ to form a lattice in $\mathbf{P}$ without satisfying the two "closure" requirements I listed. I think that your terminology is more suitable for describing the $L$ in my counterexample.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I will delete my answer within a few minutes.

Comment: I actually find the analogy to be correct, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I mean, the group inside $S$, for a semigruoup $S$ inherits the operation of the semigroup, right?

Comment: @amrsa Yes, that's right. But the point is that if you start with a monoid with identity $1$, and a group $G$ inside $M$ with identity $e$, then $1$ also acts as an identity for the elements of $G$, but does not belong to $G$. Thus you cannot say "if there is an identity for $G$ in $M$, then this identity belongs to $G$".

Comment: I see. It's not closed under a nullary operation. But I think this is as good an answer as the OP will ever get for this question. The question itself is interesting, and even if you delete this answer I'll try to retain the notion of local substructure (or subalgebra) +1 anyway...

Comment: @amrsa. OK, thank you, I will not delete my answer. I think the comments now clearly explain the difficulty of the question.